# How to get last status message of each record using SQL?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Consider the following scenario.

I have a Java application which uses Oracle database to store some status codes and messages.

Ex: I have patient record that process in 3 layers (assume 1. Receiving class 2. Translation class 3. Sending class). We store data into database in each layer. When we run query it will show like this.

```
Name     Status        Status_Message
XYZ       11           XML message received
XYZ       21           XML message translated to swift format
XYZ       31           Completed message send to destination

ABC       11           XML message received
ABC       21           XML message translated to swift format
ABC       91           Failed message send to destination
```

On Java class I am executing the below query to get the last status message.

```
select STATUS_MESSAGE from INTERFACE_MESSAGE_STATUS 
where NAME =  ? order by STATUS
```

I publish this status message on a webpage. But my problem is I am not getting the last status message; it's behaving differently. It is printing sometimes "XML message received", sometimes "XML message translated to swift format", etc.

But I want to publish the last status like "Completed message send to destination" or "Failed message send to destination" depending on the last status. How can I do that? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this:

```
select 
    i.STATUS_MESSAGE 
from 
    INTERFACE_MESSAGE_STATUS i,
    (select 
        max(status) as last_status
    from
        INTERFACE_MESSAGE_STATUS 
    where
        name = ?) s
where 
    i.name = ? and
    i.status = s.last_status
```

In the above example I am assuming the status with the highest status is the last status.

I would recommend you to create a `view` out of this select query and then use that in your codebase. The reason is that it is much easier to read and makes it possible to easily select on multiple last_statuses without complicating your queries too much.

Comment: Thank you mrhobo. Let me try this.

Comment: mrhobo - It looks something missing in your query. I am getting error. Can you please check again and update me?

Answer (score 0):

You have no explicit ordering specified. As the data is stored in a HEAP in Oracle, there is no specific order given. In other words: many factors influence the element you get. Only explicit ORDER BY guarantees desired order. And/or creating a index on some of the rows.

My suggestion: add a date_created field to your DB and sort based on that.